# Devise POST api test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

I am building User API functions by using Devise.
This is [referring tutorial](http://apionrails.icalialabs.com/book).

Here are routes:

```
api_customers_path  POST    /customers(.:format)    api/v1/customers#create {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
api_customer_path   GET /customers/:id(.:format)    api/v1/customers#show {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
PATCH   /customers/:id(.:format)    api/v1/customers#update {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
PUT /customers/:id(.:format)    api/v1/customers#update {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
DELETE  /customers/:id(.:format)    api/v1/customers#destroy {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
api_sessions_path   POST    /sessions(.:format) api/v1/sessions#create {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
api_session_path    DELETE  /sessions/:id(.:format) api/v1/sessions#destroy {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
```

What I want to know is how I can test Create api (POST).
I tried to test by using Postman, but it gives unexpected result.

[image: POSTMAN screenshot]

What is wrong with my test?
If I test GET apis, it works correct.

Answer (score 0):

You parameter names you give to your API are wrong for users generated by devise. They should be:

```
user[email]
user[password]
user[password_confirmation]
```

Also you might need an `authenticity_token` in order to this to work. You can generate one to test your API by typing this in a view.

```
<%= form_authenticity_token %>
```

Good luck!